# marginal effects in R ("margins")

Tags: r, plot, marginal-effects

I'm trying to plot the results of margin command (Average Marginal Effects) and the order of variables on the plot doesn't match the order of labels (for one label I get a value of another variable). For ggplot everything is ok (although it uses summary). Can anyone explain what is going on and how to make a proper plot? I'd be grateful :)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(broom)
library(margins)
library(Ecdat)

data(Participation)
?Participation
logit_participation = glm(lfp ~ ., data = Participation, family = "binomial")
tidy(logit_participation)
summary(logit_participation)

effects_logit_participation = margins(logit_participation)
print(effects_logit_participation)

summary(effects_logit_participation)
plot(effects_logit_participation)

effects_logit_participation = summary(effects_logit_participation)
ggplot(data = effects_logit_participation) +
  geom_point(aes(factor, AME)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = factor, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```